# How to use Spring BoneCPDataSource bean as data source for Log4j 2 JDBC appender?

Tags: spring, jdbc, log4j2, bonecp

I would like to log log4j2 messages into relational database.

Documentation for JDBC appender is [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender). I can use as database connection provider these sources:

- ConnectionFactory
- DataSource
- DriverManager

but is there some way how to use datasource bean (com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource) what we use in entire application?

Comment: You can't do that. Log4j is started up before Spring contexts get processed. You should be able to put the `BoneCPDataSource` but it will be a different instance than your Spring one.

Comment: I understand, and what about ConnectionFactory? Do you have an example? Is so, could you provide one as an answer.

Comment: I do not have an example.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it in 4 steps (step 2 & 3 are log4j2 config for web app):

**Step 1: Create log4j2.xml file (without JDBC appender) and put it in WEB-INF folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

**Step 2 : Add log4j2-web-2.x.jar to WEB-INF/lib.**

Here is the [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-web), you can download the jar from there or copy paste the dependency to your pom.xml if your using maven.

**Step 3 : Configure web.xml depending on the servlet api version**

See log4j2 [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html) for more details. Here is how you configure log4j in a servlet 2.5 web app.

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<!-- Logg -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>log4jServletFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>log4jServletFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<!-- /Logg -->

<!-- ... -->
</web-app>
```

**Step 4: Create a spring bean , inject your DataSource bean , and add JDBC Appender configuration dynamically in @PostConstruct method**

Here is the code sample ( tested with log4j 2.1 and spring 3.5)

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.ColumnConfig;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.ConnectionSource;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class LogUtils{

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  //inner class
  class Connect implements ConnectionSource {
    private DataSource dsource;
    public Connect(DataSource dsource) {
        this.dsource = dsource;
    }
    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return this.dsource.getConnection();
    }
    
  }

  public LogUtils() {
    System.out.println("LogUtils");     
  }

  @PostConstruct
  private void init(){
    System.out.println("init LogUtils");    
    final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
    ColumnConfig[] cc = {
            ColumnConfig.createColumnConfig(config, "date", null, null, "true", null, null),
            ColumnConfig.createColumnConfig(config, "level", "%level", null, null, null, null),
            ColumnConfig.createColumnConfig(config, "logger", "%logger", null, null, null, null),
            ColumnConfig.createColumnConfig(config, "message", "%message", null, null, null, null),
            ColumnConfig.createColumnConfig(config, "throwable", "%ex{short}", null, null, null, null),
            ColumnConfig.createColumnConfig(config, "salarie_id", "%X{SALARIE_ID}", null, null, null, null)
    } ;     
    Appender appender = JdbcAppender.createAppender("databaseAppender", "true", null, new Connect(dataSource), "0", "sicdb.bo_log", cc);
    appender.start();
    config.addAppender(appender);
    LoggerConfig loggerConfig = config.getLoggerConfig(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, null, null);
    ctx.updateLoggers();        
  }

  public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
  }

  public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
  }


}
```

** Limitations : [link to doc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html)**

> Applications sometimes have the need to customize logging separate from the actual configuration.
> Log4j allows this although it suffers from a few limitations:
>
> 1. If the configuration file is changed the configuration will be reloaded and the manual changes
>    will be lost.
> 2. Modification to the running configuration requires that all the methods being called
>    (addAppender and addLogger) be synchronized.
>    As such, the recommended approach for customizing a configuration is to extend one of the standard
>    Configuration classes, override the setup method to first do super.setup() and then add the custom
>    Appenders, Filters and LoggerConfigs to the configuration before it is registered for use.